# Add CatalogSearch in the Admin

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I want to show the catalog search in the admin same as in the frontend of the Magento 2 and the results should be the same on the front and admin. I need to know how can I implement this.

Comment: What's the purpose of this feature? Why is it needed?

Comment: It's gonna be hard without some HARD tinkering. For staters, I don't know if the format of $_GET parameters used in frontend filters are going to be compatible with backend URLs. Maybe a well-included iframe could do the job? But there will be limitations. Your client might be better off with using the frontend for complexe queries and fallback on the backend with a SKU in hand.

Comment: I agree with @thedotwriter tbh, this will need some heavy customization and it's gonna be a pure emotional rollercoaster :) this is why i asked why is this functionality needed - maybe it's about being able to find data quicky and for that purpose you have the global search, maybe it's something else and can be solved some other way.